# Ruby - Implementing custom sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this `array` of `Hash`:

```
hash =    
[
  {
    distance: 0.3997651063189804, project_id: 1, project_name: "Project 1", project_dependents_ids: [4]
  },
  {
    distance: 0.414026818885287, project_id: 2, project_name: "Project 2", project_dependents_ids: [1]
  },
  {
    distance: 0.6259577862775509, project_id: 3, project_name: "Project 3", project_dependents_ids: []
  },
  {
    distance: 0.43719371056189227, project_id: 4, project_name: "Project 4", project_dependents_ids: [3]
  },
  {
    distance: 0.4341702282185951, project_id: 5, project_name: "Project 5", project_dependents_ids: []
  }
]
```

I have to sort it by `distance` first, BUT, if the `project` has `project_dependents` (**self association**), it must comes after the `project` *associated*.

Ex:

A simple sort by **distances**, as below:

```
hash.sort! { |a, b| b[:distance] <=> a[:distance] }
```

... will result in:

- Project 3
- Project 4
- Project 5
- Project 2
- Project 1

But this result isn't 100% what I want. I want to sort it also by the `project_dependents`. Ex:

The result must be:

- Project 3
- Project 4
- Project 5
- Project 1 # Project 1 has less distance, BUT project 2 depends of it.
- Project 2

It's just a *simple* example. A project can have many self association ids and so on..

So, I want to know how I can implement this kind of sort. Maybe a general idea would be helpful. All the implementations that I made here got giant code and incorrect result.

Comment: If this is data from your database, this is almost certainly something you should be doing in your ActiveRecord query (`order`), *not* with `sort`.

Comment: Unfortunately this `data` isn't coming from my *database*. This is the result of some math calculations that I did in my `controller`. I just got stucked with this, it's a bit complex.

Comment: 1.In your example, the values of `:project_dependents_ids` are empty arrays or arrays containing a single dependent id. The name of the key suggests those arrays may contain more than one dependent id. Can they? 2. Can the ids be such that 2 must follow 1, 3 must follow 2 and 1 must follow 3 (in which case that impossibility would have to be identified in code)? This is not an easy problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: 1. Yes, `:project_dependents_ids` can contain more than one dependent. 2. Well, it's a problem (a circular dependence) that I've already solved (or I think I've solved) before do this kind of sort. Yes, I know it isn't an easy problem, that's why I'm stucked :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `distance` requirement, Ruby's `TSort` is exactly the tool for the job. However, I couldn't figure out how to add an extra requirement to the topological sort, so...

One idea is to start with a sorted array, then rearrange it by pushing each element just past all of its dependents. E.g. Starting with the sorted order

```
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
```

we leave 3 alone (no dependents), leave 4 alone (all its dependents are left of it), leave 5 alone (no dependents), push 2 after 1 (because 1 is its dependent and to its right), then leave 1 alone (all its dependents are left of it), and leave 2 alone (all its dependents are left of it).

This will result in an infinite loop if you have circular dependencies. It can be defended against, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader :) (E.g. you could keep a `Set` of all nodes pushed at `curr`, and clear it when `curr` is incremented; if you try to re-push the same one, raise an error)

```
array = hash # because your naming makes no sense :)
hash = array.each.with_object({}) { |o, h| h[o[:project_id]] = o }

order = array.map { |o| o[:project_id] }.sort_by { |id| -hash[id][:distance] }

order.each_index do |curr|
  dependents = hash[order[curr]][:project_dependents_ids]
  max_dep_index = dependents.map { |d| order.index(d) }.max
  if max_dep_index&.> curr
    order[curr .. max_dep_index - 1], order[max_dep_index] =
      order[curr + 1 .. max_dep_index], order[curr]
    redo
  end
end

result = hash.values_at(*order)
```

EDIT: This is not terribly efficient, all those `.index` calls, and I have this feeling it should be possible to do it better...

EDIT2: Made the loop more Rubyish.

Comment: Awesome! I just tested your `code` here and it really works, different than mine (which currently is a complete mess). Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot. Now I'll study your `code` ^^. By the way, I took a look in Tsort module and it's so great, I've never heard about it before.. too bad that it doesn't fit in my case.

Comment: Hello @Amadan, I was thinking about `TSort`.. and I think it can fit in my case if I just sort the items by `distance` first and then call `.tsort`. Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Oh, nice. I tried sorting the `each_child` order, but didn't try that. Cheers.